# Complex roots of higher order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation: $y^{(4)} - 8y' = 0$, where the $(4)$ is the fourth derivative, of course.

We get characteristic equation: $r^4 - 8r = 0 \to r(r^3 - 8) = 0$, which has real roots $2, 0$. But there are 2 other roots, which are complex, correct? I am familiar with solving basic problems in complex variables, but I'm just wondering a consistent way to find these other two roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the other roots by using the long division as follow
$$\frac{r^4-8r}{r(r-2)}=r^2+2r+4$$
by using the quadratic formula of $r^2+2r+4$ 
$$r_{1,2}=-1\pm \sqrt{3}i$$
or by this way
$$r(r^3-8)=r(r^3-2^3)=r(r-2)(r^2+2r+4)$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $ r =0$ of course and also $$r^3=8e^{i2n\pi}\implies r=2e^{i\frac{2n\pi}{3}}$$